# Get all images from device and show it in uicollectionview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I want to show all images from device to my app in uicollectionview.
and want to select multiple images from uicollectionview. I have watched numbers of programs.[ELCImagePickerController](https://github.com/B-Sides/ELCImagePickerController)

but i cant get it correctly.
please help me...
thank you

this links works fine...[Multi-Select ImagePicker](http://mutiselectimagepicker.blogspot.in/2014/08/imageselect-to-allow-multiple-selection.html)
but how can i get selected images into an array from button Done..
[image: selected images]

When I press Done button image shown in array like this....

```
<UIImage: 0x7fca78772510>, {485, 303}
```

so, how can i get this image in my collection view.. help me guys....

Comment: `ELCImagePickerController` should work. post what you have done so far and we can try working it out.

Comment: see the answer i have added i hope your problem is solve. @bhavin ramani

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get all image from gallery

View Controller header(.h) file..

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#include <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h> 

@interface getPhotoLibViewController : UIViewController
{
 ALAssetsLibrary *library;
 NSArray *imageArray;
 NSMutableArray *mutableArray;
}

-(void)allPhotosCollected:(NSArray*)imgArray;

 @end
```

implementation file

declare global count variable as

```
static int count=0;

@implementation getPhotoLibViewController

-(void)getAllPictures
{
 imageArray=[[NSArray alloc] init];
 mutableArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
 NSMutableArray* assetURLDictionaries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

 library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

 void (^assetEnumerator)( ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
  if(result != nil) {
   if([[result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType] isEqualToString:ALAssetTypePhoto]) {
    [assetURLDictionaries addObject:[result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyURLs]];

    NSURL *url= (NSURL*) [[result defaultRepresentation]url]; 

    [library assetForURL:url
             resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
              [mutableArray addObject:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[asset defaultRepresentation] fullScreenImage]]];

              if ([mutableArray count]==count)
              {
               imageArray=[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:mutableArray];
               [self allPhotosCollected:imageArray];
              }
             }
            failureBlock:^(NSError *error){ NSLog(@"operation was not successfull!"); } ]; 

   } 
  }
 };

 NSMutableArray *assetGroups = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

 void (^ assetGroupEnumerator) ( ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *)= ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
  if(group != nil) {
   [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:assetEnumerator];
   [assetGroups addObject:group];
   count=[group numberOfAssets];
  }
 };

 assetGroups = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

 [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll
                        usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator
                      failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {NSLog(@"There is an error");}];
}

-(void)allPhotosCollected:(NSArray*)imgArray
{
 //write your code here after getting all the photos from library...
 NSLog(@"all pictures are %@",imgArray);
}

@end
```

Use getAllPicture method to get photos from photo library.

OR You can have a look at this blog http://mutiselectimagepicker.blogspot.in/2014/08/imageselect-to-allow-multiple-selection.html

Comment: I have try that link and it worked...http://mutiselectimagepicker.blogspot.in/2014/08/imageselect-to-allow-multiple-selection.html